# Why I am getting error when calling the API using axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to call the API and use the API result for further computation But not able to do like this. Even after using async/await. I am getting the console value as undefined.I tried using promise as well but I am not getting how do I give authorization attribute to it.
I am naive to js, can anyone help where I am going wrong?

```js
var plan;
async function makeRequest() {

   const config = {
  "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "[Auth_url]"
  },
};
    let res = await axios(config)

    console.log(res);
    plan = res;
}

makeRequest();
console.log("plan",plan)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Show us your error

Comment: This is not even a problem of async call or not, you are just logging an undeclared variable, before even calling your function. If you logged afterwards (preferably declaring your variable as well - the non-strict voodoo of assigning global variables wouldn't have happened yet for the same reasons), see [how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Sorry I missed the global variable. But even after using async/await. I am getting the console value as undefined. Can anyone please guide where I am going wrong? I tried using promise aswell but I am not getting how do i give authorization atribute to it

Comment: "But even after using async/await" — You **aren't** awaiting `makeRequest();`

Comment: Refer to the post i linked above, it's now a direct duplicate of it.

Comment: not awaiting means?

Comment: You aren't using `await` to wait for the promise returned by `makeRequest` to resolve.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I am little confused with the link you shared..doesnt tell how to use authorization/header attribute aswell

Comment: Some amount of transfer is required, yes. It won't be copy-able code for your specific situation. The general problem is, what you need to take in (that the async call isn't finished yet, when you call `console.log`, so `plan` isn't yet assigned, and how to deal with that). It's not about the details, whether the async call is `$.ajax`, or `fetch`, or `makeRequest`, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

you can pass the token details in the headers section

```js
var plan= [];
 function makeRequest() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',      {
  headers: {
    /* 'Authorization': '',*/
  }})
    .then((res) => {
   
    plan = res.data;
    console.log(plan);
    });
}
makeRequest();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

This approach you can try in the sample snippet set you have provided.

```js
var plan;
async function makeRequest() {
   const config = {
  "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "[Auth_url]"
  },
};
    let res = await axios(config)
    plan = res.data;
}

makeRequest().then(result => {
console.log("plan",plan)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but then again the issue is same, the console is undefined, I am expecting to get the api response in the plan variable.

Comment: You: 1) didn't address the core issue at all (rather you just deleted the `console.log` in an edit), 2) changed to a `.then`, which is absolutely unnecessary, inside the original code, and 3) kept the `await`, now mixed with `then` style in the same function, but i'm out, i spent way too much time on the 10000th dupe of the same topic again. People upvote whatever they want anyways.

Comment: Though thanks for your help @ASDFGerte. will try going through that link again

Comment: @Nidhi, I have updated the answer for your approach, does that clarify your doubt?